# Installing and running a node on ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, installation

In order to install Geth, in terminal it did not work :

```
bash <(curl https://install-geth.ethereum.org)
```

and in browser also that URL did not work.

Why it showing error like this?

Link for reference: https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/getting_a_client.html

Comment: Check this: https://www.ethereum.org/cli

Answer (score 1):

The instructions you're using are for frontier - the current version is homestead.  Looks like you're trying to install the geth client, but you don't mention your OS.

These are the instructions I used: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Building-Ethereum